# Почему некорректно отображаются markdown таблицы в вопросе, но все хорошо в режиме редактирования?

Tags: дефект, редактор, markdown, таблицы

В вопросе представлены скрины для наглядности. Таблица markdown не преобразуется в нормальную таблицу, а остается текстом.

Вот как я вижу [вот этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218948/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9), скрин ниже:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Думал, что автор неправильно написал, всякое бывает. Нажимаю кнопку "править", чтобы предложить правку и вижу там:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Это явный баг платформы?

Comment: Только что попробовал, у меня таблица отобразилась и на сайте: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882523/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну это в "ответе" не воспроизводится:) а в "вопросе"?

Comment: В вопросе тоже сработало: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1218948/4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Добавь пустую строку перед и после таблицы.

На метамете видел баг, что превью и рендеринг на сервере в такой ситуации отработывают по-разному, но итоговый вариант не знаю. В любом случае, логично эти пустые строки иметь.