Дефект с отрисовкой таблицы
Описание
Таблица не отрисовывается в самом вопросе (но не в предпросмотре), если перед ней не будет пустой строки.
Пример
Какой-то текст для активации деффекта
| Метка                | Руководство по использованию                                                                                                                               | Описание метки                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| -------------------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| авторизация    | Авторизация — процесс проверки, что пользователь, программа или устройство имеет право на доступ к защищённому ресурсу. Смотри также аутентификация. |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| аутентификация |                                                                                                                                                            | Аутентификация это процедура проверки подлинности, не путать с авторизацией                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| auth           | Используйте данную метку если Ваш вопрос связан с Авторизацией и/или Аутентификацией.                                                                      | Авториза́ция (англ. authorization «разрешение; уполномочивание») — предоставление определённому лицу или группе лиц прав на выполнение определённых действий; а также процесс проверки (подтверждения) данных прав при попытке выполнения этих действий.Авторизацию не следует путать с аутентификацией — процедурой проверки легальности пользователя или данных, например, проверки соответствия введённого пользователем пароля к учётной записи паролю в базе данных, или проверка цифровой подписи письма по ключу шифрования, или проверка контрольной суммы файла на соответствие заявленной автором этого файла. Авторизация же производит контроль доступа к различным ресурсам системы в процессе работы легальных пользователей после успешного прохождения ими аутентификации. |

Дополнительно 1
Скриншот того, что предпросмотр отображается нормально, для тех участников, которые не могут посмотреть разметку вопроса по каким-либо причинам:




если перед ней не будет пустой строки - кажется где-то было про то что пустая строка должна быть

@Grundy ну тогда лучше и при предпросмотре показать что таблица неправильная.

¯\(ツ)/¯ это другой вопрос

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11213/
